# How can you prevent invoked workflow action in logic apps (standard) from retrying

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

In logic apps (standard), when using the "invoke workflow" action, there appears to be no ability to change the retry behaviour if the called workflow returns 400-500 error response status. The workflow will retry 4 times.

I need to disable the retry policy - can you?

[image]

```
"actions": {
"Invoke_a_workflow_in_this_workflow_app": {
    "type": "Workflow",
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "workflow": {
                "id": "wf-child"
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "@triggerBody()"

    },
    "runAfter": {}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling?tabs=consumption#change-retry-policy-type-in-the-code-view-editor), you can edit the `retryPolicy` to `none`:

```json
{
  "inputs": {
  <...>,
    "retryPolicy": {
      "type": "none"
    },
  <...>
  },
  "runAfter": {}
}
```

So for you, this should work:

```json
"actions": {
  "Invoke_a_workflow_in_this_workflow_app": {
    "type": "Workflow",
    "inputs": {
      "host": {
        "workflow": {
          "id": "wf-child"
        }
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": "@triggerBody()",
      "retryPolicy": {
        "type": "none"
      }
    },
    "runAfter": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this in the docs but thanks Thomas, works exactly as described!